# Git merge with commit via cherry-pick

Tags: git, merge, cherry-pick

following scenario: i have multiple branches (master/preview/release).
i am developing in master, doing periodic commits. let's call them "experimental" and "fixes".

now i want to merge selected fixes-commits to my preview-branch without the experimantal-commits.

the image should show what i mean.

[image: schema of git-repository]

now i tried it with `cherry-pick` and `rebase` but i didn't figure out how to manage that.

Comment: Firstly - 'i am developing in master', oh god. Secondly, how are you doing a cherry pick? That should be as simple as checking out the branch you wish to add the changes to and running a cherry-pick with the hash of your desired commit.

Comment: fistly: it's just a scenario to easily explain what i want to do :O
secondly: i am doing the cherry-pick as following: `git checkout preview` and then `git cherry-pick hashcode` where hashcode is the hashcode of the `ADC`-commit. as expected my file looks like that afterwards: 

`A
<<<<<<< HEAD
B
=======
D
C
>>>>>>> bbd71e0... ADC
`

Comment: There is nothing inherently special about the master branch, I don't see why you shouldn't develop there - it might not fit *your* model of development, but there is nothing immediately bad about it. Of course, it might be a good idea to commit the bugfixes in a different branch from the experimental new features - then you can just merge the bugfix branch into the experimental branch to keep things synced.

Comment: The way you're doing it sounds good. What's the matter exactly ? Got an error ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like cherry-pick is the tool you want, but from your comments it is apparent that you get a conflict. In that case, read the output of the `git cherry-pick` command carefully, it should tell you how to proceed in order to complete the cherry-pick. Generally, you have to find the conflicting files (using e.g. `git status`), resolve the conflicts, and then `git add` the resolved files. These three steps can also be replaced by using `git mergetool`. When you are done resolving, you can use `git cherry-pick --continue` to finish the operation.

You might want to think about your branch model though, generally you should not need to use cherry-pick often. Consider e.g. developing features in their own branches and merging them into the appropriate "release branches" (preview/release) when preparing a new version for those.